# How to get android system date and time format in app

Tags: android, datetime

How can i get current time format that is set in android. Like it is 12 hrs or 24 hrs. I can easily get date and time and put format on it but i want to get current format of time from android system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the following:

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a `String` you should use `android.text.format.DateFormat`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
String = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```